# DOS .exe File Decompiled in Cutter Program Showing Different Than In IDA Pro

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, dos-exe, cutter

I am having an issue when using the Cutter Reverse Engineering Program,

Here is a Segment of Decompiled Assembly, in Cutter :-

[image: Decompiled DOS.exe in Cutter]

at 0000:4ed5 in the picture I posted the .string line of text is there, whereas in IDA Pro Version 5 Free in the following Picture it shows correctly :- [image: Decompiled DOS.exe in IDA Pro 5]

I.e. from mov bp, cx to and bx, 1Eh

Is there any setting, I can change in Cutter ? Or can I untick a box in the Advanced Analysis Option at the beginning before the .exe File is decompiled ? I.e. I choose all the options, except Do not load bin information (-n) that will enable Cutter to Display the correct Assembly Instructions ? Or is there any plugin I could install to rectify this ? This issue occurs, in many parts, of the disassembled Code.

Any info and help would be much appreciated